# Evaluating an infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I've been given the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)(2x)^{2n}$$
And I have to evaluate $f(1/4)$ so find the value of
$$f(1/4)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{2^{2n}}$$
I would appreciate any help with this as I am pretty lost.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is $1/2$ the derivative of $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2x)^{2n+1}$ for $|x|\lt1/2$.  So we need $g'(1/4)$.

But $g(x)=2xh(4x^2)$, where $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=1/(1-x)$ for $|x|\lt1$.

So, $h'(x)=(1-x)^{-2}$, for $|x|\lt1$.

So, we get $g'(x)=2h(4x^2)+16x^2h'(4x^2)\implies f(1/4)=1/2g'(1/4)=1/2(8/3+16(1/16)(16/9))=20/9$.

Comment: $g(x)=xh(x^2)$ is not true. $g(x)=2xh(4x^2)$

Comment: So, we get $g'(x)=2h(4x^2)+16x^2h'(4x^2)$

Comment: Also $h'(x)=-(1-x)^{-2}$

Comment: @Tbw  ok.  i'm going to correct it.  thank you.  I disagree on $h'(x)$ though.  You're forgetting the chain rule.

Comment: oh thank you, I was definitely wrong about that

Comment: @LostInSpace your correction would halve the definition of g(x) making the final **correct** answer $20/9$

Comment: I just edited the answer to be correct. It might get approved

Comment: @LostInSpace thanks to both of you

Comment: @ChrisCuster you 're welcome. TBW  Chris's answer should be accepted then if it's now correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)(2x)^{2n}$$
$$2f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)(2x)^{2n}2=\frac {d}{dx}\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^{2n+1} \right)$$
$$f(x)=\frac {d}{dx}\left (x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(4x^2)^{n} \right)$$

With $4x^2<1, -\frac 12 < x < \frac 12$ It's the case since $x=\frac 14$
$$f(x)=\frac {d}{dx}\left (\dfrac x {1-4x^2} \right)$$
$$f(x)=\left (\dfrac {1+4x^2} {(1-4x^2)^2} \right) \implies f(1/4)=\frac {20}9$$